# $interval function being ran before it should

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have an $interval function that I want to run every 10 seconds. However, every 10 seconds when it is ran, it runs the function twice. The first time it is ran, I expect no console message, as it should be creating the array `$scope.lastCheck` however, after the first execution it will create the array, as well as log "Last check array exists". Every 10 seconds following, it logs the message twice. I read the docs and tried passing `10000, [0]` to force it to run once, but saw no change.

```
$scope.updateParking = $interval(function() {
    $http({
            url: 'url',
            method: "GET"
        })
        .then(function(response) {
            var responseScopes = response.data.scopes;
            if (typeof $scope.lastCheck == "undefined" || !($scope.lastCheck instanceof Array || $scope.lastCheck.length == 0)) {
                $scope.lastCheck = [];
                for (var i = 0; i < responseScopes.length; i++) {
                    $scope.lastCheck.push({
                        occupied: response.data.scopes[i].parking_spot.occupied
                    });
                }
            } else {
                console.log("Last check array exists")
            }
 });
}, 10000);
```

Comment: Yeah, I took out a bunch of un needed code to make it easier to read, that if statement is supposed to see if 'lastCheck' exists, and if it does not, create it.

Comment: So to clarify, the intention of the updateParking method is to poll for parking spaces every 10 seconds, but only create/update the scope's `lastCheck` array until at least 1 `responseScope` is returned. After that, always just print "Last check array exists"?

Comment: I have code that I didn't include that updates the lastCheck array. Basically I want that if statement to only trigger on the very first execution of updateParking. So it creates the array, but does not get overwritten to be blank every 10 seconds

Comment: Do multiple http request get sent (each time)? (Check the network logs (such as in Chrome dev tools))

Comment: Is this in a controller or a directive (or a directive's controller). Multiple instances tied to the same scope could be triggered. The first instance sets the value in scope and the second reads it, thus getting what you are seeing.

Comment: This is inside a controller. There is only one page view tied to this controller, which is where I am testing. If I log $scope.lastCheck in the first else, it contains all of the contents from my response.data.scopes[i].etc...

Comment: I'd recommend removing everything apart from a `console.log`, to see if it's actually the interval, or some of the other code.

Comment: I took out all of the code except the console.log, and it still ran twice.
$interval(function() {
console.log("something");
}, 5000);